# Disadvantages of Xcode7.3 with deployment target 7.0 Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, deprecated

In my iOS project following are the key points:

```
1. Xcode 7.3

2. Objective-C

3. Deployment target 7.0

4. UI designed using Xib with Autoresizing
```

Do i need to upgrade it from `Objective-C to Swift` as `ios 11, Xcode 9.2` released?

If I change `Deployment target`,warnings in project increasing, Does this affect anything?

I know this is non-coding question but I really want know.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you planning to release your app on AppStore?

Comment: @user28434 yes..i am planning to release update

Comment: Apple only accepts builds from the latest Xcode (major version must be latest, so it's 9.x now). So you will have to update your Xcode, and target to minimum supported version.

Answer (score 1):

Minimum deployment target for Xcode 9 is 8.0 not 7.0 , With coding there is no problem , but Xcode 9 storyboard add safeArea for running layout properly in iPhone x , also I don't think there is users now running iOS 7 , regarding swift or objective-c you can accomplish anything with any of them but swift is much easier , all tutorial now written in swift for new features every WWDC